# Linear System Determinant and Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For this system I calculated its determinant. And I found $2w + 2$. So for it to be determined and consistent $w \neq -1$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
wx + y - z = 4 \\ 
x + wy + z =0 \\ 
x - y = 1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
But to find the solution $(\frac{w+5}{2w+2},\frac{-w+3}{2w+2}, \frac{w-5}{2})$ I need RREF the matrix or is there some other way from the calculation I made of the determinant?

Comment: There is a direct way to invert a 3×3 matrix if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems)

Comment: @Andrei thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may solve the system by substitution.

Plug $y=x-1$ in the first two equations and add them together to eliminate $z$

solve the resulting equation for $x$ and find $y$ and $z$ from there.